# Difference between "under a consent" and "under consent"

Tags: word-usage, nuance

From what I understand, "consent" is an uncountable noun when it refers to the agreement of all of the members regarding specific matters, and it is countable when it refers to a documentation of approval.

I just want to make sure that I am understanding the nuance of the word correctly. So, if there is a sentence like this:

> The entire procedure should be under a legally binding consent.

It means the procedure should be abided and supervised by the legal documentation which provides consent/approval. On the other hand, the following sentence,

> The entire procedure should be under legally binding consent.

has a connotation that the procedure will require legal consent or approval of all of related people.

Am I correctly understanding the nuance of the word "consent"?
you are welcome to revise my question/thread if you find my writing to be unclear or grammatically wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, well analyzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. *Consent* as a noun is almost always uncountable. It is only used as a countable noun when you are referring to a document, certificate or order that grants consent, and that usage is very rare in everyday speech.